# Need help on scripting about crop with All pages.

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

**What i have:** I have 2 JavaScript files. (They are now in Menu section, thanks to [@ReFran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6022633/refran))

1. `Trim PDF's all pages by their trim size.`
2. `Crop and extract all pages by their specified name.`

**PROBLEM:** In this process before starting second script all the time, I have to activate `"Set Page Boxes"` then Manually select `"ALL"` from `page range` section then click on OK.

**What i Want:** I want to merge both script. If anyone knows how to activate `"ALL"` radio box in `Page Range` from JavaScript.

.

After running first script.(TRIM)
[image: Trim]
I want this through javasctipt.
[image: crop All]
This is finished version of extracted PDF.
[image: Finished]

Answer (score 0):

You can't activate "ALL" from the dialog via JavaScript but you don't really need to. I suspect the reason you *think* you need to is that the script assumes the trim box exists. It might not... it's not a required page box type. When the script doesn't find the trim box, it gets a null and fails. To solve your problem, your script should check for the existence of the "trim" box and if it doesn't exist, use the "crop" or "media" box instead. This gets around your manual step.